# Jquery accordion working fine locally but not online

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Hi I have a responsive website http://netzed.ca/unit.html which has textual information on the mobile version of it. the accordions work perfectly fine on system locally but when I upload the files on the server they dont.

Resize the window below 760px and you can see the layout. The features with the + sign in front of them are suppose to act like accordions

Any help is appreciated. If you need more info please let me know. thanks

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'accordion' unit.html:260
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'accordion' unit.html:260
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined ... please get rid of these errors before hand.

Comment: Why are you including two jquery libraries? `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>` and `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>`?